# how to import an excel file use the 64 bit version import export wizard

Tags: ssms, 64-bit, import-from-excel

I'm using SSMS v18.9 and am trying to import excel file (excel for microsoft 365 MSO(16.3.13801)  64bit.
I get the following error:  "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."

I've read way to many articles and it always says to run the 64 bit import/export wizard.  I think I've tried them all to no avail.  I downloaded visual studio and the necessary extensions, opened a ssis project and ran the import/export wizard from there and got the same result.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi This issue is due to the PC doesn't have Excel read drivers. Please download and install

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

or try this below choose 64 or 32 bit according to you PC.

[Download and install Microsoft 365 Access Runtime](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/download-and-install-microsoft-365-access-runtime-185c5a32-8ba9-491e-ac76-91cbe3ea09c9?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Are there any particular reason that you need to use 64 bit? if not follow these [steps](https://support.sentryone.com/s/article/Run-an-SSIS-Package-in-32-Bit-Mode) switch between 32 and 64 bit